# What's the difference between the mro method and the __mro__ attribute of a class?

Tags: python, abc, method-resolution-order

I stumbled across this extra, no-underscores `mro` method when I was using `__metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta`. It seems to be the same as `__mro__` except that it returns a list instead of a tuple. Here's a random example ([ideone snippet](http://ideone.com/aEhzAw)):

```
import abc
import copy

class Life(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def reproduce(self):
        pass

class Bacterium(Life):
    def reproduce(self):
        return copy.deepcopy(self)

wiggly = Bacterium()

print wiggly.__class__.__mro__
# (<class '__main__.Bacterium'>, <class '__main__.Life'>, <type 'object'>)

print wiggly.__class__.mro()
# [<class '__main__.Bacterium'>, <class '__main__.Life'>, <type 'object'>]
```

I found later that this isn't unique to `ABCMeta` but is available in all new-style classes.

So... why? What is this doing that `__mro__` isn't?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Directly from [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.mro):

> This method can be overridden by a metaclass to customize the method resolution order for its instances. It is called at class instantiation, and its result is stored in [_*mro*_](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__).

So, `mro()` is called on instantiation and caches its result in `__mro__`. They don't really have the same purpose.

Comment: So when should I use which? Does the standard implementation of `mro()` use `__mro__` as a cache, in that it does not recompute? If yes, then that's the reason for `__mro__` and should be considered an implementation detail. Otherwise, what's the purpose of it?

Comment: @burnpanck. `__mro__` is explicitly used by `super`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/typeobject.c#L2678 Can check this out in the Python CAPI to see how .mro() method is called by the interpreter.