# Where does the `__mro__` attribute of a Python's class come from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say there is some class:

```
class Test():
    pass
```

(1)[Somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713585/whats-the-difference-between-the-mro-method-and-the-mro-attribute-of-a-clas/19828965) on SO and in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) i read next:

> `mro()` called at class instantiation, and its result is stored in `__mro__`.

Okay, that is still clear to me, cause in `__mro__` something is really stored:

```
Test.__mro__                                                         
Out[48]: (__main__.Test, object)
```

Again, [somewhere](https://learning-python.com/PyRef5E-preview--Formal-Inheritance-Rules.pdf) i read this:

> To look up an attribute name Python searches:
> a)Search the `__dict__` of all metaclasses on the `__mro__` found at
> C’s `__class__`.
> b)If a data descriptor was found in step a, call its `__get__()`
> and exit.
> c)Else, call a descriptor or return a value in the `__dict__`
> of a class on C’s own `__mro__`.
> d)Call a non-data descriptor found in step a.
> e)Else, return Metaclass-tree values

I can find out that there is no `__mro__` in `Test.__dict__`:

```
'__mro__' in Test.__dict__                                           
Out[49]: False
```

So accordingly to `e` clause from previous quote i guess that
`__mro__` should be taken from "Metaclass-tree values" and hence from `type.__dict__`

Really, there is `__mro__` in `type.__dict__`:

```
["mro:<method 'mro' of 'type' objects>",
"__mro__:<member '__mro__' of 'type' objects>"]
```

1. So what was mentioned above in (1) about `mro()` result stored in `__mro__` attribute from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) doesn't really works this way?
2. How does `<member '__mro__' of 'type' objects>` results to `(__main__.Test, object)`?

Maybe you could show some source code to understand what really happens when i call `Test.__mro__`..

Comment: Note that ``Test.__dict__`` is missing all sorts of attributes – compare ``{attr: attr in Test.__dict__  for attr in dir(Test)}``. An "attribute of ``thing``" is *not* equivalent to a "key in ``thing.__dict__``". ``__mro__`` is just example of many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__mro__` "attribute" is a [data descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), similar to [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). Instead of fetching the `__mro__` attribute value from `__dict__`, the descriptor fetches the value from another place or computes it. In specific, a `<member '...' of '..' objects>` indicates a descriptor that fetches the value from an VM-internal location – this is the same [mechanism used by `__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

```py
>>> class Bar:
...     __slots__ = "foo",
...
>>> Bar.foo
<member 'foo' of 'Bar' objects>
>>> 'foo' in Bar.__dict__
True
```

Descriptors are inherited without duplication, and thus do not appear explicitly on subclasses.

```py
>>> class Foo(Bar):
...     __slots__ = ()
...
>>> Foo.foo
<member 'foo' of 'Bar' objects>
>>> 'foo' in Foo.__dict__
False
```

The precise working of such a `member` data descriptor is implementation defined. However, logically they work the same as a `property` using an internal storage:

```py
class FooBar:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        # attributes stored internally
        # the "_data" of a member is not visible
        self._data = [foo, bar]

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._data[0]

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self._data[0] = value

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._data[1]

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        self._data[1] = value
```

Comment: sorry, but would you mind to expand on the phrase `a member indicates a descriptor that fetches the value from an VM-internal location` a bit?
Does it mean that
`type.__mro__` - it's member descriptor from `type.__dict__`, which just implemented in this way by default in Python's primitive `type` in `C code "level"` ?
Cause in case of `class Foo` we have `<member 'foo' of 'Bar' objects>` but we also have `'__slots__' in dir(Foo) -> True`, while `'__slots__' in dir(type) -> False`..

Comment: ``__slots__`` is a way to request creation of a ``member`` descriptor on a class. It is not the only one, and internally a ``member`` descriptor can be explicitly created. In fact, you can freely remove ``__slots__`` after the descriptor has been created without any ill effect.

Comment: Could you say where to read more about `member` descriptors?

Comment: AFAIK these are not succinctly documented anywhere – they are a combination of several advanced concepts and implementation details. The most authoritative source is reading the actual implementations, e.g. CPython's or PyPy's source code.